# Positivity of an alternating series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Greetings esteemed mathematicians.
I've managed to prove that the following series

\begin{equation}
f_{\lambda}(\omega)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n(2n+\lambda)\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{6})}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\omega^{2n}
\end{equation}

with $\lambda > 0$

converges $\forall \omega$. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can determine for which values of $\lambda$, $f_{\lambda}(\omega) > 0 \forall \omega$? Are there any known conditions for an alternating power series to converge to positive values?

Cheers,
Allen

Comment: Numerical simulation suggests that $\lambda > 0.51277$ works, but I have no idea how to prove this. The following representation $$ f_{\lambda}(\omega) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} (\lambda \cos(\omega x) - \omega x \sin(\omega x)) x^{-2/3} e^{-x^2} \, dx $$ already reveals a competition between two function, though.

Comment: I detect a typo in the integral from the last comment. I'm getting that $$f_{\lambda}(\omega) = 2 \int_0^{\infty} t^{1/3} (\lambda \cos(wt) - wt \sin(wt)e^{-t^2} dt,$$ which surprisingly is revealed by *Mathematica* to have a closed-form in hypergeometric functions. I'm going to post a quick answer to show how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, let 
$$\hat{f}_{\lambda}(\omega) := \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n (2n+\lambda) \frac{\omega^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \lambda \cos(\omega) - \omega \sin(\omega).$$
Now by an integral representation for the gamma function of the form 
$$\Gamma(n+1/6) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{n-5/6} e^{-t} dt,$$ if we integrate the first function termwise we get (after the substitution $s^2 = t$): 
$$f_{\lambda}(\omega) = \int_0^{\infty} 2 s^{1/3} \hat{f}_{\lambda}(\omega s) e^{-s^2} ds = \frac{1}{3} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(3 \lambda \cdot \, _1F_1\left(\frac{2}{3};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{w^2}{4}\right)+2 w^2 \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{5}{3};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{w^2}{4}\right)\right).$$ 
Now look at the graphs of the components of this last function corresponding to the coefficient of $\lambda$ and the remainder terms (plots shown below):

[[image: coefficient of <span class=]$\lambda$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndwq2.png)
[[image: Remainder terms not depending on <span class=]$\lambda$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlnAL.png)

A little experimentation shows some examples which yield different signed behavior for $\omega$ around, and off, the origin:

[image]
[image]

There's probably a way to make this precise with calculus and letting $\lambda \equiv \lambda(\omega)$ depend on the other parameter, however, this shows the general method.

Comment: I know this is late, but thanks!